# iPhone notification icon

Tags: iphone, icons

On my program icon i want to show how many show a number, like on the AppStore program icon, where it shows how many updates are available. How can i implement this on my own program icon?

Comment: This is a feature of the 3.0 notification services 3.0 sdk which is under nda.

Comment: I suggest you gain access to the 3.0 SDK and read the documentation there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your application can add a badge icon number by calling:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1; // any NSInteger
```

This is available in [iPhone 2.0](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/applicationIconBadgeNumber), but in 3.0 the application doesn't have to be running to update the number using the push notification service (requires server in the cloud).